# Finding the generating function of $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

I am new to generating function and I am stuck with this problem, any suggestion on how to solve it. Thank you

Comment: Firs of all, do you know the existence of a closed form expression for $\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} k^2$ ?

Comment: Have you worked on this subject  ? Besides have you been given a methodology for example, how to find the generating function of Fibonacci sequence ?

Comment: I am trying to find the closed form of this summation using ordinary generating function

Comment: You haven't answered my first question...

Comment: I haven’t work much on this subject, but I know the generating formula for Fibonacci sequences

Comment: The formula I was referring to is $\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} k^2=\dfrac16 n (n+1)(2n+1)$, though you can do without it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the terms of the generating function

$$G(x)=1x+(1+4)x^2+(1+4+9)x^3+(1+4+9+16)x^4+\cdots$$

in this way :

$$\begin{array}{ccccc|r}
&&&&&\text{sum of lines}\\
\hline
1x&1x^2&1x^3&1x^4&\cdots&x\dfrac{1}{1-x}\\
&4x^2&4x^3&4x^4&\cdots&4x^2\dfrac{1}{1-x}\\
&&9x^3&9x^4&\cdots&9x^3\dfrac{1}{1-x}\\
&&&16x^4&\cdots&16x^4\dfrac{1}{1-x}
\end{array}$$

(the sum of lines are consequence of the famous formula for the sum of a geometric series).

Summing the last column, we get

$$G(x)=\underbrace{(x+4x^2+9x^3+16x^4+\cdots)}_{\gamma(x)}\dfrac{1}{1-x}$$

The first factor, $\gamma(x)$, is the generating function of the squares of integers, simpler to be analyzed.

You will find how one can obtain a closed form formula for $\gamma(x)$ at the end of paragraph 2.4 page 5 of this excellent [MIT document](http://www.math.cmu.edu/~lohp/docs/math/2011-228/mit-ocw-generating-func.pdf)
how to obtain a compact form for $\gamma(x)$.

For more information about the sequence of so-called pyramidal numbers, see [here](https://oeis.org/A000330).

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 0} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 z^n
&= \sum_{k\ge 1} k^2 \sum_{n=k}^\infty z^n \\
&= \sum_{k\ge 1} k^2 \frac{z^k}{1-z} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k\ge 1} k^2 z^k  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k\ge 1} (k(k-1)+k) z^k  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(z^2 \sum_{k\ge 1} k(k-1) z^{k-2} + z \sum_{k\ge 1} k z^{k-1}\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\sum_{k\ge 1} z^k + z \frac{d}{dz}\sum_{k\ge 1} z^k\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(z^2 \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{z}{1-z} + z \frac{d}{dz}\frac{z}{1-z}\right)  \\
&= \frac{1}{1-z} \left(z^2 \frac{2}{(1-z)^3} + z \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\right)  \\
&= \frac{z(1+z)}{(1-z)^4}
\end{align}

Comment: [+1] This derivation is more classical than mine, therefore more advisable to a newcomer in the field...